# Best practice when using multiple forms - vb.net

Tags: vb.net

What is the best practice for having many different menus/screens/forms in a visual basic program? Would it be to just make a new form for each menu or screen that I want? Or are there other better options?

I am not trying to make this overly complicated, I have a group project to work on and we all have different skill levels. That said it has peaked my curiosity so I figured it wouldn't hurt to ask before I got started.

Comment: Browser-based or Windows forms?

Comment: Please clarify your requirements. How many different functionality areas will you have? Solution depends on your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see this question being closed pretty quickly as being too open ended so allow me to get in my key gripe on this before that happens... no .Visible property for TabControl pages? Seriously, Microsoft??

Which brings me to the key point. If the forms are in some way related but not necessarily identical I prefer to use a single form with different tabs, despite that glaring shortcoming in the control. (Which you don't have to look far to find workarounds for on SO, but a workaround is still a workaround.) Dynamically manipulating controls at run time is another side of this coin, though one that I tend to use more rarely... but that's just a personal thing.

In a recent application, for instance, I had lists of several types of objects. They were related, but performed quite different functions and the user wouldn't really need to look at more than one list at once. As a result I used one form with a tab for each object list to keep the users' display less cluttered.

Similarly when doing a GL app recently I had the journal header and journal line entries (which go to different tables in the back-end database) in separate parts of the one form. On the other hand asset creation was sufficiently different that I created a different form, despite the creation process sharing some of the underlying data. (That is, journal line data.)

I don't believe in the concept of "best practice" because what's a good practice in one situation may be a very bad one in another. However the "rules of thumb" that I use are:
- Keep the number of forms to a minimum to keep overhead low and reduce maintenance BUT
- If there is no logical "tie" between two functions, don't be afraid to make a new form because trying to maintain one form which performs 7 different roles is a guaranteed path to madness and frustration, especially if you break something inadvertently.

Yes, the two rules conflict, but in a way I see this aspect of design as being akin to database normalisation; there's a sweet spot between over-normalising (a separate form for each and every display) and under-normalising (trying to shoe-horn too many unrelated functions into one form). At the very least the rules always give me pause to think "do I need this form, or does it relate to something that I've already done?"

And the third rule of thumb is, obviously... always look at it from the point of view of your user. Are they going to feel like you're bouncing them around too much? Do all of the forms share a look and feel and, more importantly, control layout so that they always know where to find something?

All of these things will vary from app to app, and there's never one size that will fit all IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, when I am dealing with multiple forms, I use `MDI Parent Form` to avoid multiple items in the windows task bar.

Another unusual solution is to set each forms `ShowInTaskbar` property to false.

Comment: Unless it is a small project (like it probably is in OP's question), I would avoid using MDI concept - it is not as productive as it can be, when done the Microsoft way.